# Visual Studio bothersome message: "Locating source"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dialog

During debugging a C# Consoleproject, about once an hour, I get the following error for a mind-boggling 20-30 seconds:

[image: a]

The weird part is that the source files are stored on a local SSD hard drive....
This is a workflow-disruptive completely unacceptable nuisance. Googling didn't amount to anything, do you know how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long delays are usually associated with network timeouts.  There is one setting that can affect this.  Right-click your solution node in the Solution Explorer window, the one on top of the tree, Properties, Common Properties, Debug Source Files.  Verify that the list contains directories that are not stored on a disconnected network drive.

> a mind-boggling 20-30 seconds

If you are sure about the length of the delay then it is not very likely to be a network timeout, it is too short.  That kind of delay is associated with another scourge on programmers' machines, notably on an uptick in the past few months.  It is the kind of delay you get from anti-malware.  One of your files tripping the pattern of a known virus.  The canonical example of such a problem [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099199/vs2013-very-strange-behaviour).  Also has a hint on how to detect it and the recommended workaround.

If none of this pans out then you'll need the help of the techniques outlined in Mark Russinovich's blog posts.  Lots of examples of him using his tools to troubleshoot problems like this.  A sampler is [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/07/02/3506849.aspx), doesn't match your problem but shows his approach.

Comment: I think you may be spot on with the first suggestion. There is a disconnected network drive that I used slightly over a year ago (and posed the question 10 months ago). The path was stored in the .suo. Nevertheless, I won't know straight away if this worked since the error only occurs ever so rarely (and arbitrarily) and I will probably realize after dozens of hours: "Hey, I haven't seen that error in a while..." (which is when I'll come back and grant the bounty)

Comment: Look no further, that's the cause.